# ReactJS Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

**fakeMovieService.js:**

```
const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
//and a few more movie objects of the same format
];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}
```

**movies.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";

class Movies extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies(),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="jumbotron text-center">
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Vidly</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Vidly</h1>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Genre</th>
              <th scope="col">Stock</th>
              <th scope="col">Rate</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.movies.map((element) => (
              <tr key={element._id}>
                <th scope="col">{element.title}</th>
                <th scope="col">{element.genre}</th>
                <th scope="col">{element.numberInStock}</th>
                <th scope="col">{element.dailyRentalRate}</th>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

I'm getting this error:

> react-dom.development.js:13413 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I know we're supposed to get this error when you return an object as it is without having any of the "tags", but I've checked my code and it doesn't seem like I'm returning an object as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.genre` is an object and you are actually trying to render it explicitly.

```
<th scope="col">{element.genre}</th> // here your code fails
```

You could e.g. point directly to the `name` field inside `element.genre` object to compile successfully.

```
<th scope="col">{element.genre.name}</th>
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now omg... Thank you so much! For some reason I had completely forgot that genre was also an object. You're a life saver <3